# Are there any modifications to the jQuery UI datepicker which adds time selection?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Are there any modifications to the jQuery UI datepicker which adds time selection? I googled and I found [this](http://blog.w3visions.com/2009/04/date-time-picker-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/), but I don't really like the sliders... Is there something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of other options around that I've found in the past:

This one's quite neat, although I had some problems getting it to work correctly...

http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

This one used to be there (and good), but for me at least is currently offline

http://milesich.com/timepicker/